# MSBuild property expansion creates a new line in the Exec command

Tags: msbuild

I am having some problems running a powershell script in a targets file that is being included into some projects.

The MSBuild version is
16.11.0.36601

The following is the relevant stuff from the target file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <ScriptLocation>
    '$(SolutionDir)subdir\script.ps1'
  </ScriptLocation>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>      
<Exec Command="powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File $(ScriptLocation)" />
```

My problem occurs when the property is expanded. For some reason it appears on a new line, this makes the command fail.

This is the Output:

```
0>powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File 
            'C:\code\app\subdir\script.ps1'
        
0>The command cannot be run because the File parameter requires a file path. Supply a path for the File parameter and then try the command again.
```

and then script.ps1 is opened in my default editor.

So essentially it's running `powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File` and then continuing and trying to run the next line, i.e.  'C:\code\app\subdir\script.ps1'

I can't make this work at all - even when I replace it with the documented method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files#executing-a-windows-powershell-script-on-the-build-server

When I do that - the following happens:

```
0>powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -Command "&{ &'
            C:\code\app\subdir\script.ps1
        ' } "
0>The string is missing the terminator: '.
0>    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
0>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
0> 
0>''' is not recognized as an internal or external command
...
```

Is there a way to tell MSBuild NOT to expand the property on a new line? If not, Is there a way I can wrap things so this doesn't happen?

Rewriting the script in batch or equivalent is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a property, it includes any line breaks into that property.

This:

```
  <ScriptLocation>
    '$(SolutionDir)subdir\script.ps1'
  </ScriptLocation>
```

is not the same as this:

```
<ScriptLocation>'$(SolutionDir)subdir\script.ps1'</ScriptLocation>
```